# Using C Dynamic allocation using malloc and realloc

Tags: c, realloc

I am having some trouble using the malloc and realloc functions in C and saving values in them using 2 seperate functions

Note i have only recently just started using c and porbably there are multiple bugs in the code but my main focus is saving the values to the struct

i need to be able to save multiple values to a single array.

these are my functions

```
int ArrayCreate() {

  int *pt;

  pt = (ASet *)calloc(1,sizeof(ASet));
  pt == NULL;

  return *pt;
}

//possible 2nd *
void ArrayAdd(ASet **arrayStruct, int x) {

  ASet *pt = NULL;

  *arrayStruct=realloc(*arrayStruct,1*sizeof(ASet));
  pt = arrayStruct;
  *arrayStruct->value = x;

  free(pt);
}
```

and in my main i have

```
ASet *arr_pt = NULL;
```

to create an array

```
 printf("a new array is created \n"); 
 arr_pt = ArrayCreate();        

 break;
```

to add something to an array

```
 printf("Enter integer \n");            
 scanf("%d",&x);

 ArrayAdd(arr_pt,x);

 while (getchar() != '\n') {
   continue;
 }

 break;
```

also to test i have added this but i am not sure about it

```
void ArrayShow(ASet *arrayStruct) {

  ASet *pt = arrayStruct;

  //printf("%d \n", pt[0].value);
  printf("%d \n", pt[1].value);
  printf("%d \n", pt[2].value);
  printf("%d \n", pt[3].value);
  printf("%d \n", pt[4].value);
}
```

i only need to know how to save correctly using realloc and calloc but for some reason the pt[0] is ignored and anything after p[1] is garbage

Comment: What do you mean by `there are multiple bugs in the code `?

Comment: So lean how to use a debugger.  That is not our job.

Comment: More specifically: what output did you expect, and how did what you get differ from that?

Comment: Please rewrite the whole main function in one block! and use some comments!

Comment: i only need to know how to save correctly using realloc and calloc but for some reason the pt[0] is ignored and anything after p[1] is garbage

Comment: Don't use int and int*. Use a correctly-typed pointer.

Comment: That `ArrayCreate()` function doesn't make sense. (And it leaks memory.) Why are you returning an `int`? What is `pt == NULL;` supposed to do? Why are you casting the return value of `calloc()`? **Why haven't you turned on compiler warnings?**

Comment: ArrayCreate This does not make sense. also There is a need to manage the size of the dynamic array.

Answer (score 1):

simple sample

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef int Item;

#define PRN_Item "%d"

typedef struct da {
    size_t size;
    Item *value;
} ASet;

ASet *ArrayCreate(void){
    return calloc(1, sizeof(ASet));
}

void ArrayAdd(ASet *arrayStruct, Item x){
    ASet *ap = arrayStruct;
    Item *p = ap->value;
    p = realloc(p, (ap->size + 1)*sizeof(Item));
    if(p){
        ap->value = p;
        ap->value[ap->size] = x;
        ap->size += 1;
    } else {
        perror("realloc");
        exit(1);
    }
}

void ArrayShow(ASet *arrayStruct) {
    Item *v = arrayStruct->value;
    size_t n = arrayStruct->size;
    while(n--){
        printf(PRN_Item " \n", *v++);
    }
}

void ArrayDrop(ASet *arrayStruct){
    free(arrayStruct->value);
    free(arrayStruct);
}

int main(){
    ASet *arr_pt = ArrayCreate();

    if(!arr_pt){
        perror("ArrayCreate");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("a new array is created \n");
    while(1){
        int x;
        printf("Enter integer \n");            
        if(1!=scanf("%d", &x))
            break;
        ArrayAdd(arr_pt, x);
    }
    ArrayShow(arr_pt);
    ArrayDrop(arr_pt);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

The line below is a comment so it's not executed:

```
//printf("%d \n", pt[0].value);
```

And your casting to `pt` with the wrong type that's why you're getting garbage

/* replace Aset with int and SIZE must be a defined size */
    pt= calloc(SIZE, sizeof(int));

`pt == NULL` is a comparaison expression not an assingment statment:

```
pt = NULL // assining NULL to pt
```

`ArrayCreate` must return a pointer to the fisrt element of the array, not the value of the address pointed to:

```
int *ArrayCreate() {

int *pt;

pt = calloc(SIZE,sizeof(int));
pt == NULL;

return pt;
}
```

Comment: Don't cast `malloc()`: it is not needed, potentially dangerous, and _above all_ : it will confuse the OP.

Comment: thanks for your help i changed the calloc function and removed pt==NULL (that line was extra only now i realised)

Comment: but still its the same

Comment: @user3137308 paste you're whole code here pastebin.com and provide the link

Comment: No, in `C`, void pointers can be assigned to and from _any_ pointer type (except function pointers) without a cast.

Comment: @wildplasser ok i got it!

Answer (score 0):

Problems:

1. There's no visible record of how big the array is, so you can't tell what size to reallocate.
2. Your `ArrayCreate()` function should return a pointer to the structure.  The `pt == NULL;` statement does nothing; your compiler should be warning you about a statement with no effect. Because you are returning an `int` and not a pointer, you are leaking memory.
3. Your `ArrayAdd()` function doesn't know how much space to allocate (point 1 again). The code should not be using `free(pt)`; `realloc()` may have returned a pointer to the same location or to a different location, but either way, it has dealt with the old memory.

---

> I did not understand the 1, 2; so you're saying `pt` should be `*pt`? What effect will that have and 3 the part about how much space?

Consider the `ArrayCreate()` function — as currently written:

```
int ArrayCreate() {

  int *pt;

  pt = (ASet *)calloc(1,sizeof(ASet));
  pt == NULL;

  return *pt;
}
```

First of all, the code is confused about whether it is dealing with `int` or `ASet` types.  It appears to be allocating an array with 1 (zeroed) `ASet` element but assigning that to an `int *`.  The next line should probably be an `if` statement.  The code should probably read:

```
ASet *ArrayCreate(void)
{
    ASet *pt = (ASet *)calloc(1, sizeof(ASet));
    if (pt == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Memory allocation failed!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    return pt;
}
```

I don't object to the cast on the return from `calloc()` as long as you reassure me that you always compile with options such that if you forget to include `<stdlib.h>`, your code will not compile.  For example, I mainly use GCC and always compile with options such as:

```
gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition -Werror ...
```

If you don't compile like that, then you're better off omitting the cast.  As you'll notice, there are others who are not as flexible about the issue of casting the return from `malloc()` et al.  (I even use those options on other people's code on SO; it is sometimes painful getting their code to compile cleanly.)

The error handling or memory allocation is about the simplest available option — report the error (on standard error, be it noted) and exit.  You can be as creative as you like about how to handle the error, but failing fast has many merits in many situations.

Now, the code I've shown is more or less coherent, but the only way you know that there's one element in the array of `ASet` values is ... because it was just created with one element.

When you call `ArrayAdd()` the first time, you can assume that there was one element in the array, but when you call it another time, you have no idea how many rows are in the array, so you'll still allocate 2 elements to the array, even though that's a no-op.  You need to know, somehow, how many elements are already in the array.

As currently written:

```
void ArrayAdd(ASet **arrayStruct, int x) {

  ASet *pt = NULL;

  *arrayStruct=realloc(*arrayStruct,1*sizeof(ASet));
  pt = arrayStruct;
  *arrayStruct->value = x;

  free(pt);
}
```

You take the (pointer to the) array that you're passed, and resize the array to one element.  The `pt = arrayStruct;` line should generate compilation warnings; you're assigning an `ASet **` to an `ASet *`; they're very different types.  The `free(pt)` is simply wrong — irredeemably wrong.  You need code something like:

```
void ArrayAdd(ASet **arrayStruct, size_t new_size, int x)
{
    ASet *pt = realloc(*arrayStruct, new_size * sizeof(ASet));
    if (pt == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Memory allocation failed!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    pt[new_size-1].value = x;
    *arrayStruct = pt;
}
```

Again the code fails fast on memory allocation failure. It is careful not to clobber `*arrayStruct` before it knows that it is safe to do so.  It assigns `x` to the `value` member of the last element of the array. Note that `realloc()` does not zero the extra memory it makes available.  The code also does not know how big the array was before; it can't tell whether the array is growing or shrinking — only the calling code is privy to that information.

So, this isn't a very good bit of code, but it is better than what was there before.

Comment: i did not understand the 1, 2 so your saying pt should be *pt? what effect will that have and 3 the part about how much space i did not understand

Comment: thanks this is helping alot but the problem is i cannot use variable length arrays so i cannot use size

Comment: @user3137308 He did not talk of VLA. The new size is required when you are trying to extend the memory because of  ensured by realloc.

Answer (score 0):

there are a few things wrong with your code here are some:

- instead of `pt == NULL;` you should do `pt = NULL` because using the first compares between `pt` and `NULL` and doesn't assign `NULL` to `pt`
- this `pt = arrayStruct` is illegal because `pt` is of type `ASet` while `arrayStruct` is of type `**ASet` you should replace it with `pt = *arrayStruct`
- here `*arrayStruct->value = x;` it's like you're asking for the address of the member `value` to be changed to `x` you should instead do `*(arrayStruct)->value = x;`